# How do I install the following driver on ubuntu? (USRP1)

Tags: driver, gnuradio, usrp

I am unable to install the USRP1 driver to use gnuradio and openbts on an Ubuntu 18.04 system.

http://openbts.org/w/index.php?title=USRP1

Building gnuradio with the following command

```
./configure --disable-all-components --with-fusb-tech=libusb1 --enable-usrp --enable-gruel --enable-gnuradio-core --enable-gr-usrp --enable-config --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

gives

> component usrp has errors

the usrp directory does not have a 'configure' script either.

[image: USRP folder]

How would I build and install gnuradio properly to work with my USRP1 device?

Comment: Tried on 12.04, still unable to build